# Cutpoint/threshold not determined using R?

Tags: r

Please find `My data` below. `q` constitutes a sample of 100 cases.

I have two covariates `follow.up` and `hematoma`, each indicating follow up time (in days) and the event of a post-surgically bleeding after specific procedure.

Based on the `cumulative incidence curve` below, it seems that the risk decreases after the initial couple of days. I wish to mark or estimate *after how many days* the slope flattens.

[image]

I have applied `library(maxstat)` but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
maxstat.test(Surv(follow.up, hematoma) ~ 1, data=q, smethod="Median", pmethod="HL", alpha=0.05)
```

Which yields

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of "LogRank"
```

Which intuitively is wrong as there are no subgroups, and therefore no need for a LogRank? Even changing `smethod="LogRank"` does not solve the problem.

Can you help me apply `maxstat` to determine a cut-off (or by any other method)?

```
q <- structure(list(hematoma = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), follow.up = c(699.2430556, 
55.21180556, 272.2604167, 2077.253472, 735.1770833, 193.125, 
13.25347222, 81.19444444, 81.28125, 115.2881944, 1015.260417, 
0.5, 216.21875, 1471.298611, 10.13194444, 182.2673611, 178.2743056, 
10.24652778, 143.2013889, 194.2881944, 13.28125, 122.2291667, 
115.2743056, 154.2395833, 1026.28125, 112.25, 11.27083333, 924.1076389, 
21.27986111, 0.1, 78.26388889, 110.1805556, 419.2638889, 185.2291667, 
140.1840278, 13.26388889, 157.2256944, 126.2847222, 1860.246528, 
150.21875, 13.26041667, 12.28472222, 12.29166667, 27.20833333, 
185.25, 168.21875, 84.19097222, 479.2569444, 101.2708333, 1120.243056, 
12.21527778, 13.17708333, 164.2013889, 115.2708333, 294.28125, 
150.15625, 13.18055556, 164.28125, 125.28125, 539.1701389, 138.2291667, 
18.28819444, 269.25, 518.2847222, 1505.131944, 1153.28125, 238.21875, 
202.25, 11.19513889, 4.034722222, 311.2569444, 206.2777778, 1699.246528, 
217.2777778, 175.2465278, 13.28472222, 122.1631944, 448.2395833, 
6.274305556, 196.1458333, 171.2708333, 1349.229167, 101.5590278, 
13.24652778, 13.58680556, 181.4340278, 96.16666667, 136.2881944, 
1153.295139, 553.2569444, 131.2638889, 1629.260417, 143.2361111, 
300.2673611, 3.1875, 237.2361111, 130.2777778, 363.1840278, 105.2708333, 
150.1770833)), .Names = c("hematoma", "follow.up"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```